# Which feed does Magento's attribute "In Feed" refer to?

Tags: seo, magento, rss

I have been researching Magento's RSS feeds and there is an attribute for new products called 'In Feed'. My understanding was that this determined whether or not the product was added to the RSS Feeds, however having enabled magento's RSS, the "In Feed" attribute seems to have no bearing over whether a product is included or not. Also the only information I can find on the "In Feed" attribute says

> "Options available are Yes/No. Specifies whether you would like to
>   include this product in your website store RSS feed."

... which I also find confusing because it mentions Feed singular however Magento provides several feeds. Can anyone shed any light on the "In Feed" attribute for me, specifically what feed it adds products to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'In Feed' attribute basically allows you to opt out of feeds (any and all) by selecting No, but selecting Yes doesn't automatically place the product into any particular feed.

The settings for each feed will determine which products show - but they will only select from the subset of products who have opted into being in a feed.